# C# - keydown event when form is not active

Tags: c#, events, keydown

Hi I am making an application sort of like a mouse macro where when you press F it will move the mouses position between two spots, everything works the only issue I am running into is that I want this to work in the background as in when the form isnt pulled up on my screen. How can I do this? If anyone can help me that would be awesome.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
    {
        PointConverter pc = new PointConverter();
        Point pt = new Point();
        pt = (Point)pc.ConvertFromString("60, 700");
        Cursor.Position = pt;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        pt = (Point)pc.ConvertFromString("600, 700");
        Cursor.Position = pt;
    }
```

Comment: whats with the two downvotes already? can you guys just answer the question?

Comment: Please show us what you did, what you tried, we will not write the code for you!

Comment: Start by posting some code

Comment: three downvotes but nothing is wrong with the question...

Comment: my question doesnt involve code I simply need to know how to make the keydown event work when the form is inactive

Answer (score 0):

The events only apply to the form while its active. You cannot use events in a form in the background. Instead use the `GetKeyState` function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

Take a look at virtual key codes too. I made an application that listens for key presses in the background once. I had to use `GetKeyState` in a loop that checked every virtual key code to see if it has been pressed. But sounds like for your application you just need to check for the hot keys you want to listen out for.
You'll need to run a thread in the background for your loop or use a timer maybe.

-Edit-
Here's some more code to implement the `GetKeyState` function.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern byte GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);
```